# Running a .sh script when container starts up after executing docker run

Tags: docker

I know multiple instances of this question exist already, but I wanted to get suggestions as to what is the best way to approach this particular problem would be. My command is:

```
docker run --gpus all --rm --shm-size=1g --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 -eMODEL_NAME=xxxx -ti -v/home/xxxx/xxxx:/xxxx nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.03-tf1-py3
```

Now once inside the docker, I want to run these commands

```
cd /xxxx
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcurl3 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
touch /opt/tensorflow/horovod-source/.eggs/easy-install.pth
pip install tensorflow-probability==0.8
pip install xxxx
pip install opencv-python-headless
python ./xxxx/xxxx.py  --model_dir=xxx
exit
```

Now how would I combine all of this into a script? I don't have access to the `Dockerfile` since I am using `nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.03-tf1-py3`. What are my best options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file called `commands.sh` in `/home/xxxx/xxxx` with your contents, then run this command in your **host** machine:

```
chmod +x /home/xxxx/xxxx/commands.sh
```

Now run the container with this command:

```
docker run --gpus all --rm --shm-size=1g --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 -eMODEL_NAME=xxxx -ti -v/home/xxxx/xxxx:/xxxx nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.03-tf1-py3 sh /xxxx/commands.sh
```

Comment: Ahh, simple and effective! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to run multiple commands in docker, use /bin/bash -c with a semicolon ;

```
docker run image /bin/bash -c "cd /some/path; python a.py"
```

In this case the second command (python) will be executed only if the first command (cd) returns no error or an exit status. To avoid this use && instead of ; (semi-colon)

```
docker run image /bin/bash -c "cd /some/path && python a.py"
```

Comment: What if I add all of my commands into a bash script? Can I call it using `docker run image /bin/bash script.sh`?

Comment: follow this link https://www.edureka.co/community/10736/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-docker-at-once

Comment: That forum does not answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: try that by placing u r commands in the script.sh and run the command

Comment: Yeah not working, especially in my case since the `bin/bash` is giving me permission denied

Comment: can you try by giving executable permissions to u r script (chmod +x) , or instead of bin/bash you can use shell by giving -- sh.